# Ein Wort für diese Woche oder diesen Monat

Tags: single-word-request, adverb

Das Wort "heute" bedeutet "dieser Tag", das Wort "heuer" bedeutet "dieses Jahr".

Gibt es auch ähnliche Wörter für andere Zeiteinheiten wie Stunde, Woche oder Monat, zumindest in Dialekten oder in früheren Zeiten?

Comment: Glaube nicht, dass es Wörter dafür gibt (oder gab); man könnte aber analog zu "heuJer": "heumer" und "heuwer" bilden. ;-)

Comment: @splattne: Tja, aber kennst du alle Dialekte? Ich könnte mir schon vorstellen, dass es das irgendwann mal gab.

Comment: "heuer" laut WP: "im süddeutschen, schweizerischen und österreichischen Sprachraum „im gegenwärtigen Jahr“"; ich kenne heuer dagegen als unbestimmte Zeitangabe, im Sinne von heutzutage;

Comment: Similar to what Kage mentioned: `die Tage`. It refers to the upcoming days. `Kommt er die Tage mal vorbei?`

Answer (score 5):

"Heuer" im Bayerischen kenne ich als Synonym für "dieses Jahr".

> Heuer wird ein warmes Jahr. Wir müssen die Äpfel früher ernten als
>   letztes Jahr.

Ansonsten kenne ich "die Woche" für "diese Woche", "den Monat" für "diesen Monat"